# How to show logs in Parse Dashboard Logs View

Tags: logging, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, parse-dashboard

The Parse Dashboard has a Logs view that should show Logs that Parse produces.

Currently all we're getting is the LiveQuery started logs and no errors. So we know the logs can be read but not how to tell Parse to log them here.

I've searched online for the Docs for this feature but they don't seem to exist.

Could someone point out how to get Logs to show here, and what logs can be shown here. i.e.: Is it just cloud code logs? Can Node logs be directed here?

Any examples or links to the docs would be greatly appreciated.

Running Parse Dashboard v 1.0.19.

Answer (score 4):

Anything that is logged using the the parse logger should show up in your dashboard logs (they do for me!).

So, some things to know:

1. only things logged with the logger in ParseServer will appear there.  Stdout and Stderr are not redirected to the log. So if you use `console.log()`, they will not show up in the logs.
2. If parse-server generates an error, it *should* be logged and show up
   in the dashboard.  I am not that familiar with the LiveQuery feature
   and it is possible that there is a path where an error is produced
   but not logged.  If you can tell me how to reproduce and its a
   logging error, I'll fix it :).
3. To log something, you can either:

---

```
const logger = require('parse-server').logger;
logger.warn('this is a log message', { foo: 'bar' });
```

---

or, in cloud code, you can use the logger on the request object:

```
 Parse.Cloud.define('cloudFunctionName', (request, response) => {
    request.log.warn('this is a log message!');
 });
```

In general, parse-server is pretty quiet.  You can make it chatty by setting the environment variable `VERBOSE=1`